# how to convert string consisted of list to real list

Tags: python, string, list

now I have the unicode object

```
u'[
    [
        [
            ["Hello","w_0","w_0,w_10",1],
            [".","w_1","",0," "],
            ["This","w_2","",0," "],
        ]
        [
            ["\u4f60\u597d","w_10","w_0,w_10",1],
            ["\uff0c","w_11","",0],
            ["\u6211","w_12","",0],
        ],
        "http://www.kekenet.com/menu/201206/187574.shtml",154191
    ]
]'
```

how can I convert it to a list object,like

```
[
    [
        [
            ["Hello","w_0","w_0,w_10",1],
            [".","w_1","",0," "],
            ["This","w_2","",0," "],
        ],
        [
            ["\u4f60\u597d","w_10","w_0,w_10",1],
            ["\uff0c","w_11","",0],
            ["\u6211","w_12","",0],
        ],
        "http://www.kekenet.com/menu/201206/187574.shtml",154191
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely evaluate strings containing Python literals.

```
from ast import literal_eval

a = '["Hello", "World!", 2]'
b = literal_eval(a)
# ["Hello", "World!", 2]
```

Note that the string can only be compromised of: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None` (taken from the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval))

Answer (score 1):

in this case you are lucky because your string appears to be valid JSON, so you can just do:

```
from simplejson import json

value = u'[
    [
        [
            ["Hello","w_0","w_0,w_10",1],
            [".","w_1","",0," "],
            ["This","w_2","",0," "],
        ]
        [
            ["\u4f60\u597d","w_10","w_0,w_10",1],
            ["\uff0c","w_11","",0],
            ["\u6211","w_12","",0],
        ],
        "http://www.kekenet.com/menu/201206/187574.shtml",154191
    ]
]'

array_value = json.loads(value)
```

For this to work it relies on the string using double-quoted strings (as per the json spec), i.e. `["Hello","w_0","w_0,w_10",1]` and not `['Hello','w_0','w_0,w_10',1]`

It has the advantage over a solution using `eval` that it is more secure... using `eval` is very dangerous if this value comes from user input or other untrusted code, whereas json is safe.

**Edit:**
As has been pointed out the string posted is not valid json... though I wonder if it's a typo?

The problem is:

```
value = u'[
    [
        [
            ["Hello","w_0","w_0,w_10",1],
            [".","w_1","",0," "],
            ["This","w_2","",0," "],
        ] <-- should be a comma here
        [
            ["\u4f60\u597d","w_10","w_0,w_10",1],
```

Comment: This `  ]\n[` is not vaid JSON.

Comment: argh you're right, that's awful

Comment: First thanks for your help.when I convert unicode above,it worked.But when I convert u'[["I","w_0",0," "],["said","w_1",0," "],["\'","w_2",0],["Hello","w_3",1," "],["Kirsten","w_4",0],["\'","w_5",0," "]],it raise ValueError: Invalid \escape.

Comment: if the data you're getting is not in a standard format you will have to do some transformations on it first, probably via regular expressions. is there a specification for the format you're receiving?  can you change the code that provides the data to just use json?   the problem in your new error is because of this `"\'"`